# Erro de importação inexistente mas reportado pelo Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html5, eclipse

Um aplicativo que estou fazendo cria um navegador e fornece as funcionalidades pela página web que esse navegador exibe.

A página faz uso de `AngularJS` para funcionar, e não tem absolutamente nenhum problema com o projeto, ele funciona normalmente.

O problema é que o Eclipse retorna erros inexistentes no projeto.

O trecho dos imports de JavaScript é este aqui:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/app.js"></script> <!-- Erro acusado aqui -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/app.services.js"></script> <!-- Erro acusado aqui -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/app.directives.js"></script> <!-- Erro acusado aqui -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/app.controllers.js"></script> <!-- Erro acusado aqui -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hopscotch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script> <!-- Erro acusado aqui -->
```

Eu consigo resolver esse problema ao mover e voltar os arquivos para a posição normal deles. Mas como fazer para consertar isso de uma vez por todas?

## EDIT

Tentei alterar o JavaScript *build path* do projeto, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

A validação do Eclipse não conseguia reconhecer os arquivos, ou seja, bastou alterar as configurações do projeto para ignorar os "erros".

[image: Problema resolvido]